# Cannot work out why this summif statement is not working

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I cannot for the life of me see why this simple sumifs statement is not working - if anyone can help me I would be so grateful I have spent a couple of hours trying to work it out and am beaten.

I have a sheet named 'Sales Tracker', column W is total money made per transaction that I want to sum, Column D is where the name of the sales consultant is populated via a dropdown box (and yes the spelling and capitalisation has been checked) and column R is a Yes or No dropdown box for was the sale won. This piece of code is on a different sheet to provide sales stats.

Thank you,

```
    =sumifs('Sales Tracker'!W3:W, 'Sales Tracker'!D3:D, "Jango", 'Sales Tracker'!R3:R, "Yes")
```

Comment: Does this return a #NA type error, or a numerical answer that is wrong?

Comment: It comes back with #N/A - Error no match. I get that this should mean that something is off but I have checked the spelling of the sales person's name, there are no spaces before or after it and the other sales person's formula (exactly the same apart from the name) works perfectly fine and brings the figure back.

Comment: It really is just baffling me and I wonder if some other setting might have been changed if that is possible? I have even tried creating an entirely new sheet and putting the same formula on that sheet and it gives me the same problem. If I then only change the sales persons name it works fine. I am probably missing something really basic but I have no clue what it is!

Comment: If the cell 'Sales Tracker'!D3 has "Jango" in it, does the formula ='Sales Tracker'!D3="Jango" return TRUE?

Comment: Helpful if you could provide a copy pf your sheet

Comment: I will just go and check John - thank you for sticking with me on this.

idfurw - I would love to but due to the spreadsheet containing peoples personal sensitive data I can't unfortunately sorry I know that would be far more useful for you to see.

Comment: Yes it does John

Comment: Seems like the error is being passed through perhaps.  Are the values in 'Sales Tracker'!W3:W themselves the output of formulas?  Have you scanned the entirety of them( as well as columns D and R) to make sure there are no #N/A errors?

Comment: Hey MattKing thanks for joining in - So basically I have a data sheet where I have the data validation for the columns:

Column D just has two names as drop down options 
Column R is either Yes or No from a drop down as well
Column W is a currency value that is calculated via a formula however, the exact same sumif formula works for the other sales persons name using the same columns so this is why I am so confused as to why its not working. There are no #N/A results in any of the above mentioned columns either.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: It's very hard to help you without having a spreadsheet to look at. It doesn't need to be an original one, just an spreadsheet to see what could be happening. Would that be possible?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY({'Sales Tracker'!W3:W, 'Sales Tracker'!D3:D, 'Sales Tracker'!R3:R}, 
 "select sum(Col1) 
  where Col2 = 'Jango' 
    and lower(Col3) = 'yes'")
```